# Adding a bar to a bootstrapped firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm trying to develop my first firefox extension and I chose a bootstrapped one, because I can do it easily (not having to install nothing). Now, I'm trying to find at least some documentation to start, and I really need to know how can I add a panel to the browser, something like the history panel, but with some personalized components, as buttons and inputs.

I'm so confused because there are a lot of ways in developing extensions, but I really want to preserve bootstraped method. Any idea how to add the panel or what to read? (I already have read this, and didn't helped https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Extensions/Bootstrapped_extensions )